# Iterating through a Dictionary isn't working properly

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary and create a new textblock for each item in the dictionary, based on a particular property in each object within the dictionary.  However, when iterating through, it is only ever finding the most recently added object, then repeating this for however many objects in the dictionary. i.e. i will have 4 textblocks all with identical text if i have 4 objects in there.  Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong?  Here is my code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MyObjects> entry in MyDictionary)
{
   MyTextblock = new TextBlock();
   MyTextblock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);
   MyStackPanel.Children.Add(MyTextblock);
   MyTextblock.Text = MyObjects.name;
}
```

Comment: I should add that when debugging through, i can see the right number of objects and properties in the dictionary

Comment: You're not using `entry` within the loop?  Should it be `entry.Value.name`?

Comment: For that code to compile at all the `name` property has to be static in the class, and that means that you don't have a name for each entry. All entries share the same name, so when you set the name for the last entry, that will also be the name for all previous entries. Even if you use `entry.Value.name` instead of `MyObjects.name` the name will still be the same. You need to have a non-static property for the name for each entry to have a name of its own.

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to use the entry object like that :

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MyObjects> entry in MyDictionary)
 {
     MyTextblock = new TextBlock();
     MyTextblock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);
     MyStackPanel.Children.Add(MyTextblock);
     MyTextblock.Text = entry.Value.name;
 }
```

Comment: and James Thorpe.  Thank you both! That was the problem...its now working :)

Answer (score 0):

A more correct way would be to iterate on the Dictionary [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

```
foreach (string Key in MyDictionary.Keys)
{
    MyTextblock = new TextBlock();
    MyTextblock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);
    MyStackPanel.Children.Add(MyTextblock);
    MyTextblock.Text = MyDictionary[Key].name;
}
```

And even a better option in this case, since your loop doesn't seem to use the key anywhere, is to iterate over the [`Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

```
foreach (MyObjects Value in MyDictionary.Values)
{
    MyTextblock = new TextBlock();
    MyTextblock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);
    MyStackPanel.Children.Add(MyTextblock);
    MyTextblock.Text = Value.name;
}
```

Comment: How is that better? You're doing an additional lookup per iteration.